# How to call a action inside If statement in Ember Js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Iam new to ember, Below is my ember js code for  loop the entity array, in the if statement im cheking two ids are equal for render check box as disable, but this approach is not working, how can do this in ember js,

```
 {{#each this.model.data as |entity|}}
    
                <tr >

                {{#if entity.workflowTask.id == this.currentlyLoggedUserId }}

                  <td><input type="checkbox"  disabled="false"> </td>
                  {{else}}
                  <td><input type="checkbox"  checked={{this.allChecked}} onclick={{action 
                 (action "getSelectedMerchant" entity.id) value="target.checked" }} > </td>
                  {{/if}}
    </tr>
```

Comment: Please add the ember version you're using and what isn't working. If you're using a newer ember version then the answer in idiomatic Octane will be a bit easier to read, but may not work in unsupported older versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to create a helper. Which check your two ids are equal or not.

```
import { helper } from "@ember/component/helper";

export default helper(function isEqual(params /*, hash*/) {
const [val1, val2] = params;
return val1 === val2;
});
```

Then your template you need to do:

```
{{#each this.model.data as |entity|}}
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    disabled={{(is-equal entity.workflowTask.id 
    this.currentlyLoggedUserId)}} />
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Err I am just wondering how this could be an answer if it doen't call any actions? And surely you can add a custom helper but I'd say these ones are pretty standard for this kind of problem https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers.

Comment: yaa you are right. ember-truth-helpers is nice for those kinds of situation

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly what isn't working, but I might write this as:

```
{{#each this.model.data as |entity|}}
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    disabled={{(eq entity.workflowTask.id this.currentlyLoggedUserId)}}
    {{on "click" (fn this.getSelectedMerchant entity.id)}}
  />
{{/each}}
```